# aspnet-sessionid layout renderer not saving sessionid in database using NLog logging framework

Tags: c#, database, oracle, logging, nlog

Below is the NLog config, to save to database target. Able to save all the parameters except "SessionVal". Layout used for "SessionVal" is "${aspnet-sessionid}". Its saving as null in database.

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
        name="databaselog"
        connectionStringName="MyContext"
        commandType="StoredProcedure"
    commandText="SP_NEWNLOG">


  <parameter name="EXP_SOURCE"    layout="${event-properties:item=EXP_SOURCE}" />
  <parameter name="STACKTRACE"    layout="${event-properties:item=STACK_TRACE}" />
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" dbtype="DateTime" />
  <parameter name="PAGE_URL"    layout="${event-properties:item=Page_Url}" />
  <parameter name="LOG_LEVEL"    layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="messageVal"    layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="Corelationid"    layout="${event-properties:item=CoRelId}" />
  <parameter name="SessionVal"    layout="${aspnet-sessionid}" />
  <parameter name="QUERY_STRING"    layout="${event-properties:item=QUERY_STRING}" />
  <parameter name="IPADDRESS"    layout="${event-properties:item=IPADDRESS}" />
  <parameter name="BROWSERINFO"    layout="${event-properties:item=Browser_Info}" />
  <parameter name="LoginId1"    layout="${event-properties:item=LOGINID}" />
  <parameter name="PrevPageUrl"    layout="${event-properties:item=PrevPageUrl}" />
  <parameter name="ENVIRONMENT"    layout="${machinename}" />
  <parameter name="ErrorCoRelID"    layout="${event-properties:item=ErrorCoRelID}" />
  <parameter name="IsNewSession"    layout="${event-properties:item=IsNewSession}" />
  <parameter name="LOGGERNAME"    layout="${logger}" />
</target>
```

I have to save sessionVal into database.
Any help is welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Check the internal log: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: checked internal-logging, There no exceptions or no errors. But the value at aspnet-sessionid is empty string ``.

Comment: Please post the log (trace level)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673133/unable-to-save-aspnet-sessionid-using-nlog ?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3951