# Unable to save aspnet-sessionid using NLog

Tags: asp.net, log4net, nlog, sessionid

I'm working with Nlog logging framework. currently I'm facing issue, that unable to save aspnet-sessionid.

```
<target xsi:type="File"name="LogFileAppender"fileName="C:\Users\acer\Downloads\test1.txt"
        layout="${longdate} ${aspnet-sessionid} - ${message} "/>
```

It is saving (as per layout) in target fileName like

**2020-05-07 11:16:56.4047 - Global.asax.cs:Application_Start(): Application initializing, starting cache load**

But in log4net I'm able to save aspnet-sessionid

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="C:\Users\acer\Downloads\test1.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.log"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %aspnet-session{SessionID} - %message"/>
  </layout>
```

It is saving (as per conversion pattern) in target fileName like

**2020-05-06 12:09:49,560 26aef5e9-16-132332207751900447spnet-session{SessionID} - Global.asax.cs:Application_Start(): Application initializing, starting cache load**

The problem is, with log4net logging framework I'm able to save aspnet-sessionid but not with NLog framework.Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to enable NLog InternalLogger and check for warnings/errors? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mistake with log4net Conversion pattern only.

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %aspnet-session{SessionID} - %message"/>
```

In this conversionpattern, for %aspnet-session{SessionID} in log4net it will consider only %a and it will be appdomain conversion pattern.

So , its in NLog will be like

```
<target xsi:type="File"name="LogFileAppender"fileName="C:\Users\acer\Downloads\test1.txt"
    layout="${longdate} ${appdomain} - ${message} "/>
```

So, its confusion with name of conversion pattern for aspnet-sessionid in log4net.

[https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppDomain-Layout-Renderer] refered for appdomain layout renderer.

Answer (score 1):

This NLog `${aspnet-sessionid}` renders the following:

- [HttpContext.Session.SessionID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpsessionstatebase.sessionid)

This Log4net `%aspnet-session{SessionID}` renders the following:

- [HttpContext.Session.Content["SessionID"]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpsessionstatebase.item)

It is matching this NLog LayoutRenderer: `${aspnet-session:SessionID}`

See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/AspNetSession-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Tried this ${aspnet-request:item=SessionID} layout in NLog, still it's null only.

Comment: @Shree Think I read the source code wrong. Believe it should match NLog `${aspnet-session=SessionID}` (Have updated the answer)

Comment: I tried with this, but getting error like "LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-session=SessionID'. Is NLog.Web not included?" , after including NLog.dll also.

Comment: After adding NLog.Web.dll aso , I'm getting this error. "LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'aspnet-session=SessionID'. Is NLog.Web not included?"

Comment: @Shree Oops make a mistake. Should be a colon instead of equals. So `${aspnet-session:SessionID}`